# Binding 2 Integer arrays to DataGridView and make it updating when elements of the arrays changed

Tags: c#, arrays, datagridview

I tried to bind 2 Integer arrays to DataGridView and make it updating when elements of the arrays changed, but failed to update when elements of the array changed.

```
 var row = new DataGridViewRow();
                for (int i = 0; i < lastN; ++i)
                {
                    row.Cells.Add(new DataGridViewTextBoxCell()
                    {
                        Value = minutesMax[i]
                    });
                }
                dataGridView1.Rows.Add(row);
                var row2 = new DataGridViewRow();
                for (int i = 0; i < lastN; ++i)
                {
                    row2.Cells.Add(new DataGridViewTextBoxCell()
                    {
                        Value = minutesMin[i]
                    });
                }
                dataGridView1.Rows.Add(row2);
```

The 2 array are defined as below, and them posted well into a datagridview, but when the elements of the arrays are changed, the values in the datagridview failed to update simultaneously.

```
const int lastN = 21;
    int[] minutesMax = new int[lastN];
    int[] minutesMin = new int[lastN];
```

Comment: can't see any code related to update, can you update the question?

Comment: you have to update the `DataGridView` when elements in arrays are changed, since there is no `binding` between the `DataGridView` and arrays.

Comment: Thanks Kenny! Good points! However, HOW TO DO IT?

Comment: Binding to a `DataTable` is a good choice, just like `Triple K`'s answer, when there is update to the arrays, write code to update the `DataTable` accordingly and the `DataGridView` will refresh itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `Triple K`'s DataTable is 21 rows x 2 columns, not fitting to the `DataGridView`, I provide a new answer to your question.

Construct a `DataTable`(2 rows x 21 columns) from your arrays, and use it as the `DataSource` of `DataGridView`.

```
const int lastN = 21;
int[] minutesMax = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 ,21};
int[] minutesMin = { 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 ,22};

DataTable dataTable;
private void SetBinding()
{
    dataTable = new DataTable();
    for (int i = 0; i < lastN; i++)
    {
        dataTable.Columns.Add();
    }
    dataTable.Rows.Add(dataTable.NewRow());
    dataTable.Rows.Add(dataTable.NewRow());

    for (int i = 0; i < lastN; i++)
    {
        dataTable.Rows[0][i] = minutesMax[i];
        dataTable.Rows[1][i] = minutesMin[i];
    }

    dataGridView3.DataSource = dataTable;
}
```

When you update the datatable the `DataGridView` will be updated automatically.

```
private void UpdateData()
{
    minutesMin[3] = 22222;
    dataTable.Rows[1][3] = 22222;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like this,

```
    const int lastN = 21;
    int[] minutesMax = new int[lastN];
    int[] minutesMin = new int[lastN];

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < lastN; i++)
        {
            minutesMax[i] = i;
        }

        for (int i = 1; i < lastN; i++)
        {
            minutesMin[i] = (i*10);
        }
        GridBind();
    }


    void GridBind()
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dt.Columns.Add("Max");
        dt.Columns.Add("Min");

        for (int i = 0; i < minutesMax.Length; i++)
        {
            DataRow dRow = dt.NewRow();
            dRow["Max"] = minutesMax[i];
            dRow["Min"] = minutesMin[i];
            dt.Rows.Add(dRow);
        }
        dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        minutesMin[0] = 10000;
        GridBind();
    }
```

Comment: update the value in the `DataTable`, then no need to call `GridBind` again.

Comment: Sorry sir, i think `GridBind()` is needed because i only updated `minutesMin` array so need to update my `DataTable`.
So `gridView` will change automatically.

Comment: yes, you are correct. but i meant if you are not only updating `minutesMin` but also updating the DataTable (declare the DataTable as a variable of Form class), then you don't need to rebind again.